# How to check git credentials for remote on a Windows machine with PowerShell?

Tags: git, powershell, powershell-4.0, powershell-5.0

I'm currently working on a script which syncs several git repositories and updates them locally with `git fetch --prune` and `git pull`.

Now I try to automate the first run of the script, where the git credential manager would prompt for the remote credential.

Is there any change way to check / test if there is already set a credential for the remote (origin) with PowerShell?

Note: I already tried to find a workaround with `libgit2sharp` but got stuck...

---

**Used Approach**

- Since git-credential manages uses the *WindowsVault* on Windows systems I, decided to test the credentials there.
- Therefore I used the PowerShell module [CredentialManager](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/CredentialManager) to test and store the required credentials:

  - `Get-StoredCredential -Target "git:https://<GitLab_FQDN>"`
- So with these I can check the credentials for remote host before invoking any git command.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
git config --list --show-origin
```

In case of credentials you can see something like `credetial.helper=wincred`.